# How to fix graphical issues with Qt applications? (dolphin:14635): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, kde, qt, dolphin

I'm on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela (i.e. Ubuntu 14.04) and all my `QT`-based applications have been ugly after an upgrade (text is scrambled, menu content disappear, cf. screenshot below).

#### Environment

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Release:        17.2
Codename:       rafaela
```

- KDE: `4.14.2`
- Dolphin: `4.14.2`

#### Error

```
$ dolphin
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment.

(dolphin:14220): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0

(dolphin:14220): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_direction: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(dolphin:14220): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_direction: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I have similar issue with:

- `smplayer`,
- `vlc`, `
- `digikam`
- and other `qt`-based applications

#### Screenshot

[image: dolphin qt visual bug]

#### Related

- [How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?](https://askubuntu.com/q/692825)
- [Upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 Wily and get QNativeImage: Unable to attach shared memory segment](https://askubuntu.com/q/693136/22343)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the answer from [Upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 Wily and get QNativeImage: Unable to attach shared memory segment](https://askubuntu.com/q/693136/22343) with the following command:

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native dolphin
```

and it works! The UI doesn't have the bug anymore.

#### Permanent solution

Refer to the solution from [above question](https://askubuntu.com/a/694276/22343), edit `/etc/environment` to add:

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
```

Possible values are `native`, `raster` and `opengl`.

Answer (score 1):

I found an other solution for this issue here:

[QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment on KDE QT application](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2302639)

> Finally I can fix this issue by disabling MITSHM lib.
>
> This can be done by adding following line to `~/.profile` file. (ie: `system env var`)
>
> `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1`